# Not all duplicates are deleted from a text file in Python

Tags: python, duplicates

I am new to Python. I am trying to delete duplicates from my text file by doing the following:

```
line_seen = set()

f = open('a.txt', 'r')
w = open('out.txt', 'w')

for i in f:
    if i not in line_seen:
            w.write(i)
            line_seen.add(i)

f.close()
w.close()
```

In the initial file I had

```
hello
world
python
world
hello
```

And in output file I got

```
hello
world
python
hello
```

So it did not remove the last duplicate. Can anyone help me to understand why it happened and how could I fix it?

Comment: The second `hello` in `a.txt` is on the last line of the file, which means it does not end with a newline character `\n`. When you iterate over the lines via `for i in f:`, where `i` is the current line, `i` will always end with a newline character, if one is present in the file. Basically, `"hello\n"` and `"hello"` are not the same string.

Comment: Kudos for using set()!

Comment: @gnight - he is using set already. I'm so curious... As you can see, the line_seen is set. He need to study set().

Comment: To OP, please check following code once you study set type. `print('\n'.join(set(f.split())))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is with the break line characters ("\n") which appears at the end of each line but the last line. You can use a combination of `set`, `map` and `join` function such as what follows:

```py
f = open('a.txt', 'r')
w = open('out.txt', 'w')
w.write("\n".join(list(set(map(str.strip,f.readlines())))))
```

##### out.txt

```
python
world
hello
```

If you want to stick to your previous approach you can use:

```py
line_seen = set()

f = open('a.txt', 'r')
w = open('out.txt', 'w')

for i in f:
  i = i.strip()
  if i not in line_seen:
    w.write(i)
    line_seen.add(i)

f.close()
w.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

The first line probably contains `'hello\n'` - the last line contains only `'hello'` - they are not the same.

Use

```
line_seen = set()

with  open('a.txt', 'r') as f, open('out.txt', 'w') as w:

    for i in f:
        i = i.strip()            # remove the \n from line
        if i not in line_seen:
            w.write(i + "\n")
            line_seen.add(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you didn't end the last line with a newline. The known line is `hello\n'. The last just 'hello'

Fix the input or strip() the read `i`

Answer (score -1):

```py
# Since we check if the line exists in lines, we can use a list instead of
# a set to preserve order
lines = []

infile = open('a.txt', 'r')
outfile = open('out.txt', 'w')

# Use the readlines method
for line in infile.readlines():
    if line not in lines:
        # Strip whitespace
        line = line.strip()
        lines.append(line)

for line in lines:
    # Add the whitespace back
    outfile.write("{}\n".format(line))

infile.close()
outfile.close()
```